# I want to connnect to Sql Developer Database using eclipse java code

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do i connect to the sql developer database from eclipse, can i get the drivers to be installed and the java code to connect to the database

I am using Eclipse Jee 2019

Comment: Which Application Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Developer is just a client, it has no database

Answer (score 0):

To connect with oracle database you need below:

Driver class: in case of oracle its "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver".

Connection URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER_NAME:PORT:SERVICE_NAME

UserName & Password of Oracle DB.

```
//step1 load the driver class  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

//step2 create  the connection object  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER_NAME:PORT:SERVICE_NAME");  

//step3 create the statement object  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

execute any queries using stmt:
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
```